# apn_sender gem doesn't send pushes on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following code:

```
    options = { alert: "123", badge: "+1", sound: true }
    User.find_each do |user|
        APN.notify_async(user.device_token, options)
    end
```

Also I put `apn_development.pem` in `config/certs` folder. This code correctly works on my local machine, but it doesn't work on production server - I don't get any pushes from my Rails App. What's the problem? How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe environment files contains some relevant to this gem code. You can also start server in production mode on your machine, and try to debug it.

Comment: I don't have MySQL on my local machine :) Are there another ways? :)

Comment: Well, you can change db production config on dev, if you have enough data to perform necessary actions.